# Index a Interface with a const enum and infer type in a switch statement in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums, switch-statement, type-inference

I am trying to automatically infer the type of some data passed in a `switch` statement based on the `enum` value fulfilling the `case` condition.

To achieve this I've defined a const enum:

```
const enum MESSAGES {
  open = 1,
  close,
  redo
}
```

Then I use it to index a `Interface`:

```
interface MessagePayloadContent {
  [MESSAGES.open]: string;
  [MESSAGES.close]: number;
  [MESSAGES.redo]: boolean;
}
```

At this point I define the object that I will evaluate in the `switch` statement:

```
interface MessagePayload<T extends MESSAGES> {
  scope: T;
  content: MessagePayloadContent[T];
}
```

Finally I use the above in a switch statement.

I would expect that the interpreter can infer, based on the value being passed to each `case`, what type of data will be contained in the `object`.

On the contrary I get the errors as in the comments in the code below:

```
function pick(payload: MessagePayload<MESSAGES>): void {
  switch (payload.scope) {
    case MESSAGES.open:
      open(payload.content); // Argument of type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      break;
    case MESSAGES.close:
      close(payload.content as number); // This is my current workaround.
      break;
    case MESSAGES.redo:
      redo(payload.content); // Argument of type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.
      break;
  }
}

const open = (d: string) => d;
const close = (d: number) => d;
const redo = (d: MessagePayloadContent[MESSAGES.redo]) => d;
```

What I don't fully get is that in some other circumstances this does work, so I wonder why some other times it does not.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the type `MessagePayload<MESSAGES>` is not what you think it is.  Interfaces don't generally distribute over unions, so it just evaluates to:

```
interface OopsMessagePayload {
  scope: MESSAGES;
  content: string | number | boolean;
}
```

Which means that if you check the `scope` property, it does not narrow the type of the `content` property.

TypeScript does have some type-level constructs that distribute over unions, so there should be a way to define

```
type MessagePayloadDistributive<T> = ...
```

such that

```
MessagePayloadDistributive<MESSAGES>
```

evaluates to

```
MessagePayload<MESSAGES.open> |
MessagePayload<MESSAGES.closed> |
MessagePayload<MESSAGES.redo>
```

I will use [distributive conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) in which if you have a type like `type D<T> = T extends U ? V : W` where the checked type `T` is a bare type parameter, the conditional check will be distributed across unions:

```
type MessagePayloadDistributive<T extends MESSAGES> = T extends any
  ? MessagePayload<T>
  : never;

type SomeMessagePayload = MessagePayloadDistributive<MESSAGES>;
```

If you inspect that, `SomeMessagePayload` evaluates to the desired type above.  And then the following code will work as you expect:

```
function pick(payload: SomeMessagePayload): void {
  switch (payload.scope) {
    case MESSAGES.open:
      open(payload.content); // okay
      break;
    case MESSAGES.close:
      close(payload.content); // okay
      break;
    case MESSAGES.redo:
      redo(payload.content); // okay
      break;
  }
}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBhA9gE2QbwFBKXjWCgBckJgBXMJAWQFEBlJgQQHFmk8CC0ZKSALxIAjABp8veABs0UCJN5IAThAxopAXylES5foJEAKDAC4kZFQEtgAcwCUwgHxIMAbl3EyhOQuFIphbUYABGECpOQq4eXvqq6mgBQfTQUCB2EAAKIACeciAY6MCklKQA2owsHMwAdGoaALpRMZ5StqUqAGYIyHRpGdl5BUXEpSXcUgSVzGycTLWGwI0WVrZ2nsoz1fO1svIQK0gh4SqbvNtzdQ1oR6FoaDIQIMDnOlKkuQJIAEoB-VB0pkcvk0IViuMKlUrkxGm0CB0Ij1EKlAYMQSMADwAFQoAA9xhgoPRZjUmK4eLwoEQBBZsecCHpIRYAUChqDwWMyuVsXDtLgPl8+gNgcMwRgACLWNahKikawANwgOPxhOJ0LJrhEuIgBMoRKQL1yUyQAH5UWyMeKcc4TcEIEqzoLvkw0JBWeixYV-iL2SMpTK5YrlRr5s54UgulRgPB5cQkDBrPAANbGOAc8xIV3u31WwoOCwKtDWDCTZRQADu1lI8AAFoF0yNatTDE5Kcp4CB-KG6kszCblEs016MHsuSUHO4kAB6adINDJvID3ihNQgZMM6Rdvqk3b7BT95QdvwQYcZsclMqTmdzhdLo8rtcb5ed7u766JQ8PhIaM9NplXlOs7zouxrfkgq7PM+yg6AQOg6EAA)